# FreeBSD 10 guest on qemu/kvm CentOS 7 host

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, freebsd, qemu

I'm trying to install FreeBSD 10 on CentOS host without using graphics (using only serial console). I've tried:

```
# virt-install -n freebsd-a -r 512 --vcpus=1 --os-variant=freebsd10.0 --graphics none -v --disk path=/home/freebsd/freebsd-a.qcow2,size=10 --cdrom /home/freebsd/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso --network bridge=br0 --network bridge=br11 --autostart
WARNING  CDROM media does not print to the text console by default, so you likely will not see text install output. You might want to use --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

Starting install...
Creating domain...                                       |    0 B     00:00
Connected to domain freebsd-a
Escape character is ^]
```

Indeed, console is not connected. When I try to use `--location`, the installation does not start:

```
# virt-install -n freebsd-a -r 512 --vcpus=1 --os-type=freebsd --os-variant=freebsd10.0 --graphics none -v --disk path=/home/freebsd/freebsd-a.qcow2,size=10 --location /home/freebsd/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso --network bridge=br0 --network bridge=br11 --autostart
WARNING  No 'console' seen in --extra-args, a 'console=ttyS0' kernel argument is likely required to see text install output from the guest.

Starting install...
ERROR    Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/freebsd/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso'

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start freebsd-a
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

```
# mount -o loop /home/freebsd/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso /mnt/
# virt-install -n freebsd-a -r 512 --vcpus=1 --os-type=freebsd --os-variant=freebsd10.0 --graphics none -v --disk path=/home/freebsd/freebsd-a.qcow2,size=10 --location /mnt/ --network bridge=br0 --network bridge=br11 --autostart
ERROR    Error validating install location: Could not find an installable distribution at '/mnt/'

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is FreeBSD even capable of using the serial console to perform the installation? I have never seen such functionality.

Comment: "Could not find an installable distribution" ... looks to me as if some software assumes you're going to be installing a Linuxen.  Does the man page for virt-install say anything about a non-Linux distro?

As far as serial consoles are concerned, the old "sysinstall" could do that AFAIK, but I'm not sure about its replacement, bsdinstall, since v9.x ... the installer has always been a bit of an Achilles heel in an otherwise excellent server system ....

Answer (score 2):

8 years later I'm here to answer this question.

Default FreeBSD ISO/etc does not enable serial port by default(As far as I know).

I solved it by building a custom ISO.

```
1) Install FreeBSD using virt-manager GUI. You need at least 20G disk.
2) Make sure you've installed sources by selecting "src" option during GUI installation.
3) cd /usr/src
 1. vim stand/defaults/loader.conf
 2. In "Basic configuration options" section change kernel_options="" to 
    kernel_options="-h"
 3. In "Loader settings" section uncomment and change "console" setting to 
    console="comconsole,vidconsole"
 4. In "Loader settings" section uncomment and change "comconsole_speed" to 
    comconsole_speed="155200"
 5. In "Kernel settings" section uncomment and change "boot_serial" to
    boot_serial="-h"
 6. Save changes and exit the file.
 7. vim sbin/init/ttys
 8. Go to the "Serial terminals" section and change ttyu0 line to 
   'ttyu0 "/usr/libexec/getty std.155200" vt100 on secure'
 9. Save changes and exit the file.
4) make -j8 buildworld buildkernel
5) cd release
6) make release
7) make install DESTDIR=/home/username/custom_iso
8) Done. Now in a "/home/username/custom_iso" dir you have kvm-ready custom iso 
   with a serial port enabled. 

virt-install example config:

    virt-install \
    --name freebsd_13_2_serial \
    --description "Freebsd 13.2 with a serial port" \
    --os-variant=freebsd13.1 \
    --ram=2048 \
    --vcpus=2 \
    --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/freebsd_13_2_serial.img,bus=virtio,size=10 \
    --graphics none \
    --console pty,target_type=serial \
    --cdrom /home/username/freebsd_13_2_serial.iso \
    --network default,model='virtio'
```

[Screenshot of the FreeBSD 13.2 installation using a serial port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Bhk.png)